# Simple question about derivative and summation

Tags: summation, partial-derivative

I am reading a book and I have a simple question. There is this summation:

$$
A = β\sum_\textbf{x} ||\textbf{x}||^2 r(\textbf{x})$$

after this, taking the partial derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial  A }{\partial r(\textbf{x})} = β||\textbf{x}||^{2}
$$
My question is: where is the summation? The result should not be $β\sum_\textbf{x} ||\textbf{x}||^2$?

Comment: the derivatives w.r.t. the *other* $r$s will disappear as being effectively constant, which will kill all the terms in the sum except the one shown